# JOIN table rows vertically using UNION in SQL

Tags: sql, union

I have 2 tables Student and Staff, when I join them together using `UNION`

```
SELECT STUNAME, STUGENDER,
   FROM STUDENT
   UNION
   SELECT STFNAME, STFGENDER
   FROM STAFF
   ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

The name is mixing in the output, is there a way to separate them vertically like this, but still using UNION, I have assignment on this and still got stuck

```
STUNAME
Alvin
Jane
STFNAME
Lincoln
Kate
```

Comment: Clarify your question properly.

Comment: Sorry, normally using UNION will connect columns from different tables into one single column as the output, is there a way to separate the ouput rows into 2 type of name vertically? instead of display STUNAME: name1, name1...., name_n. Is there a way to make it like STUNAME:name1, name2,name3 STFNAME: name4,name5,name6 vertically using UNION?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT StuName as cName, StuGender as Gender, 'Student' as Status
   From Student
UNION
SELECT StfName as cName, StfGender as Gender, 'Staff' as Status
   From Staff
```

Fields need to be named the same, and the Status alias field will hold which classification they belong to.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question properly, you should use something like this:

```
(SELECT STUNAME, STUGENDER, 'student' as student FROM STUDENT)
UNION 
(SELECT STFNAME, STFGENDER, 'staff' as staff FROM STAFF)
order by 3,1 asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query..

```
SELECT CONCAT('Student',@curRow := @curRow + 1) AS student,STUNAME, STUGENDER FROM STUDENT JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
UNION 
SELECT CONCAT('Staff',@curRow1 := @curRow1 + 1) AS staff,STFNAME, STFGENDER FROM STAFF JOIN (SELECT @curRow1 := 0) r1;
```